# VBA creating a string based on conditions

Tags: string, vba, conditional-statements

I need to create a string of the next type:
`"<a=1 b=123 c=15 d=19 e=12345>"` (rough example)

BUT if any of these variable doesn't exist, it shouldn't be printed at all. Hard to explain, but here is an example.

Desired output: `<a=1 c=15 e=12345>`

My current output: `<a=1 b= c=15 d= e=12345>`

I can do this by many case conditions, but is there a more elegant way to do this, ideally in one statement. May be something like (just what I want to find, it's not my expectation code)):

```
print "<[if a exists]a=" & a & ", [if b exists] b=" & b ...>"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this Excel VBA? What version?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the easiest way to do this is using the iif() function. This is more or less what you ask for with [if a exists]. Not sure what condition to test because the information you have given does not make that clear. But I think you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's exactly what I need! (VBA Excel, dunno version)